# Is there any way to programmatically add prefixes to radvd without writing to radvd.conf and restarting it?

Tags: ipv6, radvd

I need to create `prefix` entries on demand to configure a quite large `IPv6` net. What I'm doing now is:

```
stop radvd
write to radvd.conf
restarting radvd
```

But this is quite painful.

I wonder if there is something like `omshell/omapi` but for `radvd` to configure it dynamically. What I want to achieve is to be able to create `subnets` and adding them to the `radvd.conf` file.

The reason why I prefer to stop the service is because there is a high chance of reload while an actual writing to the `radvd.conf` is being performed. So I rather stop the service, perform the writing and then restart.

Comment: You don't have to stop radvd while rewriting its configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You can send radvd a HUP signal and it reloads the config.

```
systemctl reload radvd.service
```

or

```
service radvd reload
```

or

```
killall -HUP radvd
```

depending on the type (age) of system you are running on.

I would write a config to a temp file, and then use mv to move it into place.  Then do the reload.  mv usually being an atomic operation if on the same filesystem.

Comment: I have seen some case where `mv` would unlike the target before calling `rename`, so there would be a brief moment where the target did not exist. But still your suggestion is still a much more sensible approach than shutting down `radvd` just to update the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another completely different alternative approach.

The quagga routing suite contains a route announcer too.

http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/docs/docs-info.html#Router-Advertisement

You can drive it via telnet (obviously from localhost) or using the vtsh command.

commands would be

```
configure term
interface eth0
ipv6 nd prefix 2001:db8:1111:2222::/64 
no ipv6 nd suppress-ra
```

It is a little bit basic. It doesn't support RDNSS (DNS server addresses).  But gives you a way to programmatically add a route announcement.